# getting directed to ASP.NET home page on browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run the following HTTP POST API Call using ASP.NET on Visual studio 2013. I created a new web application project as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateNewAPICall("test api abc");
    }
    private object CreateNewAPICall(string apiDesc)
    {
        object result = null;
        var accessKey = "myaccesskey";
        var secretKey = "mysecretkey";
        var uRLapiList = "http://myurl.com";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("apiListDesc=" + apiDesc);
        var method = "POST";
        var timeString = DateTime.UtcNow.GetDateTimeFormats()[104];
        var signature = GetSignature(secretKey, method, timeString);
        var authorization = accessKey + ":" + signature;
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(uRLapiList, "POST", bytes.Length, timeString, authorization);
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                // Return List api Data
                result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string endPoint, string method, Int32 contentLength, string timeString, string authorization)
    {
        // Some code here
    }

    private string GetSignature(string secretKey, string method, string timeString)
    {
        // Some code here
    }

    private byte[] HMAC_SHA1(string signKey, string signMessage)
    {
        // Some code here
    }

    private string CreateSignature(string stringIn, string scretKey)
    {
        // Some code here
    }
}
```

Right now, I am confused as to where to put this file in the "Solution Explorer" in order to 
run the file and get the output on my browser?

Right now I have this code inside `"Models-->Class1.cs"` directory as shown in the image below:

[image]

So, when I press `F-5` key, I am getting directed to the home page of the ASP.NET with the URL `http://localhost:4439/`

Do I need to make any changes here?

[image]

Comment: That project is set up for MVC, but your code is clearly for ASP.NET Webforms.  See if you have the option to create a new ASP.NET Webforms project.

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us Please find the options I have while creating a new project in the [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/my8EE.jpg). Do you think that I should switch to something else here?